# Odoo: add history and comments to my custom model

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I've created a custom model in Odoo and I'd like to add the same history&comments section to its form view as built-in Odoo models have (e.g. customers).

Is that possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly you need your model to inherit from mail.thread.

```
_inherit = 'mail.thread'
```

And then add the div at the end of your form.

```
        <div class="oe_chatter">
            <field name="message_follower_ids" widget="mail_followers" groups="base.group_user"/>
            <field name="message_ids" widget="mail_thread"/>
        </div>
```

and you should be away.

Presentation on it here  http://www.slideshare.net/openobject/odoo-open-chatter-integration

Comment: Thanks, this's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Do you know how to list this in a Qweb report?